# Rails faker in model files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

So i've used faker before, but im making a sort of stress test model method to be able to insert n amount of fake records for a model to test things.

However despite requiring faker in that particular model file I always get the error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- faker`. Is it not possible to use faker in model files?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the code you're using for that?

Comment: literally just `require 'faker'` at the top of the model file

Comment: How's the gem included in your application? The Rails version, the Ruby version, the gem version?

Comment: I followed the instructions by just doing a `gem install faker`. It actually doesn't seem to say anything about adding it to the gemfile.

Comment: You must add it to your Gemfile, once doing that you can use it in your application. Try that.

Comment: hmmm that doesn't seem to work either. It just doesn't seem to like the faker "require" in the model file.

Comment: It'd be easier adding code to your question.

Comment: There really isn't much to my code. I literally included faker via `require 'faker'` in my model file and called one of the methods via `Faker::Company.name` which I then receive a `I18n::MissingTranslationData (translation missing: en.faker.company.name)` when trying to do anything with the model method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check

```
require 'faker'
I18n.reload!
```

People are claining it sometimes does the trick
https://github.com/stympy/faker/issues/278